# Array is not getting filtered

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been tryping to get items (seperated by newlines) from a text file and remove selected ones in the process. I have used similar methods before and it worked, that was when i did it in `index.js`, whereas this time, i have created a new file for this to not clutter up `index.js`, but it does not seem to be working.

index.js:

```js
const items = require("item_thing.js")("./items.txt");
console.log(items);
```

items.txt:

```
a
 b
c


    d
e
f
g
a
c
e
g
```

item_thing.js:

```js
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");

module.exports = (path) => {
    let items = readFileSync(path, "utf8");
    items = items
        .split(/\r?\n/)
        .filter(i => i != "" || !i.startsWith(" ") || !i.startsWith("\t"));
    return items;
}
```

expected output:

```
[
  'a', 'c', 'e',
  'f', 'g', 'a',
  'c', 'e', 'g'
]
```

actual output:

```
[
  'a', ' b',  'c', '',
  '',  '\td', 'e', 'f',
  'g', 'a',   'c', 'e',
  'g', ''
]
```

could this be something to do with javascript being non-blocking?
could this be a bug with node.js?
or is there a fault with my code?

thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the ***or*** `||` operator to ***and*** `&&` operator.

```
items = items
  .split(/\r?\n/)
  .filter((i) => i != "" && !i.startsWith(" ") && !i.startsWith("\t"));
```

***or*** `||` operator means at least one should be correct and that is why all output are at least true for one condition.

Whereas ***and*** `&&` operator means every condition should be correct.

---

Example:

```js
// Using OR || operator
console.log(2 + 2 === 8 || 2 + 3 === 5); // True

// Using && operator
console.log(2 + 2 === 8 && 2 + 3 === 5); // False
```

Comment: i completely forgot how `.filter` works, thank you for your answer.